# How to modify image or text of style of feature?

Tags: openlayers-3

In openlayers3, in the Style Object, they don't have a method of `set('')` and also dont have `setImage()` and `setText()`. If i want to modify the image angle or text content, do someone know how to do ?

Comment: For me, i want to click on this feature, then a dialog pop up to allow me fill the angle ,then save the ne angel , finally it change this feature's angle only and rendered on map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [`ol.Feature#getStyle`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#getStyle) returns a `ol.style.Style` (or an `array`);
2. [`ol.style.Style#getText`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.style.Style.html#getText) returns a `ol.style.Text`;
3. [`ol.style.Text#setText`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html#setText) is what you want.

So can be something like:

```
feature.getStyle().getText().setText('new content');
```

Comment: That only changes the actual text of the feature, not how the text is rendered. Changing the text is only part of what @Wenhua seems to be asking

Comment: Those are the steps to access the `ol.style.Style` setters. You can do what the library let you do.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker I think this way will change all features with same value, like you said, `feature.getStyle().getText().setText('new content');` it will change all text features. For me, i want to click on this feature, then a dialog pop up to allow me fill the angle ,then save the ne angel , finally  it change this feature's angle only   and  rendered on map.

Comment: @WenhuaHu Are you able to put your code on a fiddle, we can "talk" better about it.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker here is link of fiddle.in the map, i initiate the image and add it to map in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/phc16s0k/5/. But in my application, it is kind of different. i request a external layer, which contains many images, so i dont need define them, just need to add original image features on map. What i need to do is that when i click on one of image feature, a box pop up and allow me fill the expected angle, then save it and update this new angle to this feature on map,

Comment: You don't know how to add the popup and inside it add a text field to fill with the new angle and you want me to do this. Is that right?

Comment: @Jonatas Walker  For now, i want to change the feature i clicked, but in this example, it changed all features with same angle[jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/phc16s0k/5].

Comment: @Jonatas Walker , here is steps to tell u problems, 1. click on map, it will add a image, then click on other coordinate, it also add a new image, etc  2. click on a existing image, then click on change angle, 3 zoom in or out to refresh map 4 you will find every image has rotated with same angle. here is link of fiddle.in the map, i initiate the image and add it to map in this fiddle[ jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/phc16s0k/5]

Comment: I soved it with initiating a different style object to replace using same style varible.